# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown menu on hover with animation

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

im using bootstrap 4 and i have dropdown menu in my navbar. I need to make it when i hover it, to slideDown with jquery function.

```js
  if ($(window).width() > 769) {
    $('#nav-menu #dropdown1').hover(function(){
      $(this).dropdown('toggle');
    });
  }

  $('#nav-menu .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
  });
  $('#nav-menu .dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
  });
```

This is my code. When my mouse leaves dropdown1 it closes.

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Услуги
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Услуги</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Услуги</a>
 
          </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: `.on('show.bs.dropdown'` what is that?

Comment: This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

Comment: On hover means when you hover over it will trigger/toggle but once you move your mouse off the target you're no longer hovering.  Wouldn't this in theory be functioning properly?

Comment: For example http://jsfiddle.net/blinkmacalahan/M5Ccz/ once you stop hovering the image returns to normal, hence your dropdown toggle not persisting